# Reconciling different definitions of orthogonality

Tags: signal-processing, orthogonality, correlation

I want to establish about orthogonality in my mind.

I knew the orthogonality of two functions $f$ and $g$ in interval $T$ like the following:

$$
\int_{\langle T\rangle}f(t)g^*(t)~dt=0 \tag{1}
$$
where
$$
g^*(t) \mbox{ is a conjugate of } g(t)
$$

However, in some textbooks, if
$$
\text{E}\left[f(t)g(t)\right]=0 \tag{2}\ ,
$$
then two functions $f$ and $g$ are orthogonal.

I want to know the relationship between two equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The notation $E(f)$ is most commonly used in probability theory and this means simply just $\int_{X}fd\mu$ where $(X,\mu)$ is your measure space (it is called *expectation*). Therefore the only difference between those two relations is the fact that the second uses *real* scalar product. In other words $g$ is real if and only if $\overline{g(t)}=g(t)$ for all $t$ and in this situation these two notions coincide.

Comment: Thank you, you mean the equations are same?? f and g are real signal.

Comment: I mean that if $f,g$ are real then both notions of orthogonality are the same.