# Orthogonality of Two Signals.

Tags: signal-processing, orthogonality, correlation

My last question's link: [Reconciling different definitions of orthogonality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1617653/reconciling-different-definitions-of-orthogonality)

However, I failed to understand why they are equivalent.

If $f$ and $g$ are real,
\begin{align}
\int_{<T>}f(t)g(t)~dt &= 0 \tag{1} \\\\
E\left[f(t){\cdot}g(t)\right] &= 0 \tag{2}
\end{align}

---

I made an counter-example.

\begin{align}
f(t)=\begin{cases} 1 & t\in(0, 1) \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases} \\\\
g(t)=\begin{cases} 1 & t\in(1, 2) \\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise} \end{cases}
\end{align}

Then, 
$$
\int_{0}^{2} f(t)g(t) ~dt = 0 \\
\therefore f(t) \mbox{ and } g(t) \mbox{ are orthogonal.}
$$

However,
\begin{align}
E\left[f(t){\cdot}g(t)\right] &= E\left[f(t)\right]E\left[g(t)\right] &\because f(t) \mbox{ and } g(t) \mbox { are orthogonal.}\\
&=\frac12 \cdot \frac34 \\&= \frac38 \\&\ne 0
\end{align}

---

What is wrong with me? Please give me some hints or intuitive or proofs. Thank you.

Comment: It is not true that $E[fg]=E[f]E[g]$, even when they are orthogonal.

Comment: I thought this process: correlation value is 0 = orthogonal, correlation value is 0 = uncorrelated = independent..

Comment: Can you prove the equation 1 and the equation 2 are same?

Comment: Equation (1) and (2) are equal by definition, I think. There is nothing to prove, or do you have a different definition of $E$?

Comment: I think $E[f(t)g(t)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(t)g(t)f_T(t)dt$ like $E[g(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x)f_X(x)dx$

Comment: @Crostul Thanks to your comments, I restarted to think of this problem. And I found what is my fault. Again, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood hahaha :)

My mistake is that I regarded $t$ as random variable but it is just variable.

So,

\begin{align}
E\left[{f(t)g(t)}\right] = \frac{1}{T}\int_{<T>}f(t)g(t)dt
\end{align}

for example, some function $h(t) = 3t+3$.

[image]

$$E[h(t)]=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^3{3t+3}~dt=7.5$$

---

Anyhow, $E[f(t)g(t)]$ is just scalar value times integration of two signals.